# Calculate price for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with calculating the price for each row. If I select the quantity field, it will print the same price for both rows.

Here is my demo
https://jsfiddle.net/keyro/fw8t3ehs/2/

Thank you in advance.

Html

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Price ($)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="body">
                    <tr data-id="1" data-price="20.00">
                        <td>Apple ($20)</td>
                        <td><select class="form-control product_quantities" name="product_quantities[]">
                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td class="text-right amount" name="amount[]">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-id="2" data-price="15.00">
                        <td>Banana ($15)</td>
                        <td><select class="form-control product_quantities" name="product_quantities[]">
                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td class="text-right amount" name="amount[]">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right bold">TOTAL</td>
                        <td class="text-center bold">1</td>
                        <td class="text-right bold"><b class="total">0</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Javascript

```
        function totalamount() {
        var q = 0;

        var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

        for( var i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){
            var z = $('.amount').html();
            q +=z;
        }
        $('.total').html(z);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('.body').delegate('.product_quantities','change',function(){
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var qty = tr.find('.product_quantities option:selected').attr('value');
            var price = tr.data('price');

            var total = (price * qty);
            $('.amount').html(total);
            totalamount()
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the result that you want. But I have made the code to sum the two *amount* columns properly.

Just changed the bottom of `totalamount` function to this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < rows; i++ ){
    var z = $('.amount:eq(' + i + ')').html();

    if (!isNaN(z)) {
        q +=Number(z);
    }
}

$('.total').html(q);
```

And as @mrEthol correctly pointed, this should be fixed as well:

```
$('.amount').html(total);
```

to

```
tr.find('.amount').html(total);
```

So both calculations will work.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fw8t3ehs/4/).

Comment: Thank you all, you guys. It works perfectly. Appreciated it!

Comment: @Khai nice! Remember to mark as accepted and/or upvote the answer wich works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.amount').html(total);
```

change to:

```
tr.find('.amount').html(total);
```

Comment: I edited them and works like charm. Thank you @mrEthol

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each table array and find the values and add to that rows amount only using `$(v).find('.amount').text(amt);`. I think this will help you.

```
    function totalamount() {
        var q = 0;


        $('.body tr').each(function(index, v){
            var cost = Number($(v).data('price'));
          var qty = Number($(v).find('.product_quantities').val());
          if(!isNaN(cost) && !isNaN(qty)){
          var amt = Number(cost*qty);

          $(v).find('.amount').text(amt);

          q = q + amt
          console.log(qty, cost, q);}
        })
        $('.total').text(q);


    }

    $(function () {
        $('.body').delegate('.product_quantities','change',function(){

            totalamount()
        });
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fw8t3ehs/6/)**